# OIDC client issue in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

i am working on react application which uses oidc client library to authenticate users using identity server 4. Authentication is working fine all scenarios except two.

1. When using IE in private mode
2. When using Edge in private mode

All other browsers work as as normal (both normal mode or incognito/private) modes

The code i'm using in is:

```
   Log.logger = console;
   Log.level = Log.ERROR;
   new UserManager({ response_mode: "query" }).signinRedirectCallback()
  .then(user => {
              this.signInUser = user;
   })
   .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
    });
```

I'm getting below error only in edge and IE in private mode.

> OidcClient.readSigninResponseState: No matching state found in storage
>        UserManager.getUser: user not found in storage
>        Error: No matching state found in storage

Anyone came a cross this issue? really appreciate any help

Comment: I'm also seeing this on edge and firefox, but it is working in chrome for me. I see warnings of cross browser issues in the chrome console, but they go away on deployment, and it also seems to be working on edge in deployment. I believe the only way around this (locally) would be to setup concurrency on the local npm start, and have a backend node setup to handle the routing traffic. there is more about cross server issues here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/486. Best of luck...